# Getting started with Ruby, Watir and Ruby Mine?

Tags: ruby, watir, rubymine

I want to automate testing of an e-commerce website. I installed Ruby, Watir, Gems and Ruby Mine.

Though I played around with RubyMine I could not figure how to start writing a simple script:

1. How do I start writing a simple script using RubyMine? I created a project. What is the next step? Do I have to create an rspec file now? And probably search for a sample program, and run it?
2. Can someone give me a sample of opening a website and maybe clicking a link so that I can see it running?

I would be grateful for simple documentation which helps me.

Comment: I wouldn't start with RubyMine. I would start with IRB or use a simple editor and run from commandline. Reduce the variables instead of increasing them. Reduce what you need to know, do not increase it. RubyMine is a great product but I use something simpler. There are tons of examples using google searches, including Zeljko's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Did you even check [Watir web site](http://watir.com/)? There is plenty of documentation on how to get started there.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the sample project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/cuctest.zip) that is using Cucumber and Watir to open a search page, send a query and verify the results.

`Gemfile` specifies the required gems, make sure they are installed or can be installed in your environment. If you are on Windows you need to [install DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit).

Comment: Thanks for your promt response and providing me with the sample project.I dont have cucumber installed. Can you tell me how to view your code in the .rb files(which are in features' folder)? I tried to open it from a machine where I dont have Ruby interpreter installed. Assume thats the reason why I am not able to view the contents. Please correct me if I am wrong. When I double click it, it opens a exe. When I am able to view the code, I guess I can copy and paste that code to RubyMine and run it? Thanks again.

Comment: It's a complete RubyMine project that you can just open in the IDE.

Comment: RB files are oridinary text files..  you can view them with notepad, although you won't get any sort of syntax hilighting and such there. You can also open them with RubyMine (which is a great IDE and I like it alot, but it's not the easiest place to start)   The baby-bear 'just right' is IMHO Notepad++ which is a good simple editor that knows ruby, and is a great starting editor..