# Error while running irb file

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, rubymine

This is my first program :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

ie = Watir::IE.new
ie.goto("http://www.google.com")
ie.text_field(:name, "question").set("microsoft")
ie.button(:name, "btnG").click
```

When I run it,I get the following error, could you please help. I have installed watir-webdriver before running this

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/FirstSample:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're in IRB. Go into IRB and put in 'require watir' with quotes, then try 'require watir-webdriver'

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem is caused by the fact that you have installed watir-webdriver gem but you are requiring watir gem.

Either install watir gem or require watir-webdriver gem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've just replied to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15603108/104891) with a sample project and instructions regarding DevKit installation.

Note that RubyMine needs a valid `Gemfile` to manage dependencies. All the gems that you are using [should be specified in that file](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/ruby-gems-support.html). `bundle install` should install the dependencies without errors.

If you have errors installing gems, post it as a separate question with more details, but before doing it verify that DevKit was installed properly and can build/run the sample gem from the installation guide.

Some gems may be not fully compatible with the recently released Ruby 2.0 version. If you have no luck getting it to work, try Ruby 1.9.3 instead.